Somehow memory corrupts and malloc doesn't work (unaligned tcache chunk detected)
Somehow, memory is being corrupted and any malloc gives me:
malloc(): unaligned tcache chunk detected
I tried debugging it multiple times, but it gives me absolutely no information.
It first happened on a vector push_back when the capacity needed to increase, when I made the vector reserve enough space before it just happend in another line.
This is the relevant snippet (at least I think it happens there):
void BVHGenerator::generate(Mesh *mesh) {
    triangles.clear();
    triangle_indices.clear();
    nodes.clear();
    std::vector<t_shader_triangle> shader_triangles = mesh->getShaderTriangles();
    for (int i = 0; i < mesh->triangleCount(); ++i) {
        triangles.push_back(shader_triangles[i]);
    }

    t_bvh root_node = {};

    root_node.triangle_count = triangles.size();
    root_node.triangle_offset = triangle_indices.size();

    for (int triangle_index = 0; triangle_index < triangles.size(); ++triangle_index) {
        triangle_indices.push_back(triangle_index);
    }

    makeBounds(&root_node, getTriangles(&root_node));
    nodes.push_back(root_node);

    std::vector<int> current_nodes = {0};

    for (int i = 0; i < depth; ++i) {
        std::vector<int> new_nodes;
        for (int node_index : current_nodes) {
            t_bvh *node = &nodes[node_index];
            if (node->triangle_count < 2) {
                continue;
            }
            auto [split_side, split_middle] = chooseSplit(node_index);
            std::vector<int> left_triangles;
            std::vector<int> right_triangles;
            left_triangles.reserve(node->triangle_count);
            right_triangles.reserve(node->triangle_count);
            for (int j = 0; j < node->triangle_count; ++j) {
                int triangle_index = triangle_indices[node->triangle_offset + j];
                auto [include_left, include_right] = distributeTriangle(triangles[triangle_index], split_side, split_middle);
                if (include_left) {
                    left_triangles.push_back(triangle_index);
                }
                if (include_right) {
                    right_triangles.push_back(triangle_index);
                }
            }

            t_bvh left_node = {};
            t_bvh right_node = {};

            left_node.triangle_offset = triangle_indices.size();
            for (int triangle_index : left_triangles) {
                triangle_indices.push_back(triangle_index);
            }
            left_node.triangle_count = left_triangles.size();

            right_node.triangle_offset = triangle_indices.size();
            for (int triangle_index : right_triangles) {
                triangle_indices.push_back(triangle_index);
            }
            right_node.triangle_count = right_triangles.size();

            makeBounds(&left_node, getTriangles(&left_node));
            makeBounds(&right_node, getTriangles(&right_node));

            node->left_index = nodes.size();
            new_nodes.push_back(nodes.size());
            nodes.push_back(left_node);
            node->right_index = nodes.size();
            new_nodes.push_back(nodes.size());
            nodes.push_back(right_node);

            node->has_children = true;
        }

        current_nodes = new_nodes; // gl_rays/src/mesh/bvh.cpp:87
    }
}

Here, it crashes on current_nodes = new_nodes;. If I remove
left_triangles.reserve(node->triangle_count);
right_triangles.reserve(node->triangle_count);

it crashes on right_triangles.push_back(triangle_index);, when it tries to increase the cap of the right_triangles vec.
The gdb backtrace:
malloc(): unaligned tcache chunk detected

Thread 1 "gl_rays" received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
__pthread_kill_implementation (threadid=<optimized out>, signo=signo@entry=6, no_tid=no_tid@entry=0) at pthread_kill.c:44
44            return INTERNAL_SYSCALL_ERROR_P (ret) ? INTERNAL_SYSCALL_ERRNO (ret) : 0;
(gdb) bt
#0  __pthread_kill_implementation (threadid=<optimized out>, signo=signo@entry=6, no_tid=no_tid@entry=0) at pthread_kill.c:44
#1  0x00007ffff78a86d3 in __pthread_kill_internal (threadid=<optimized out>, signo=6) at pthread_kill.c:78
#2  0x00007ffff784fc4e in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/posix/raise.c:26
#3  0x00007ffff7837902 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#4  0x00007ffff7838767 in __libc_message_impl (fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff79c2330 "%s\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:132
#5  0x00007ffff78b27e5 in malloc_printerr (str=str@entry=0x7ffff79c59b8 "malloc(): unaligned tcache chunk detected") at malloc.c:5772
#6  0x00007ffff78b70e4 in tcache_get_n (tc_idx=<optimized out>, ep=<optimized out>) at malloc.c:3183
#7  tcache_get (tc_idx=<optimized out>) at malloc.c:3199
#8  __GI___libc_malloc (bytes=64) at malloc.c:3320
#9  0x00007ffff7ab83ec in operator new (sz=64) at ../../../../libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/new_op.cc:50
#10 0x000000000040e2c8 in std::__new_allocator<int>::allocate (this=0x7fffffffcfc0, __n=16) at /usr/include/c++/14/bits/new_allocator.h:151
#11 0x000000000040ce83 in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<int> >::allocate (__a=..., __n=16) at /usr/include/c++/14/bits/alloc_traits.h:478
#12 std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_allocate (this=0x7fffffffcfc0, __n=16) at /usr/include/c++/14/bits/stl_vector.h:380
#13 0x000000000040d032 in std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_allocate_and_copy<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int const*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > (this=0x7fffffffcfc0, __n=16, __first=15, __last=18831264)
    at /usr/include/c++/14/bits/stl_vector.h:1621
#14 0x000000000040bde8 in std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::operator= (this=0x7fffffffcfc0, __x=std::vector of length 16, capacity 16 = {...}) at /usr/include/c++/14/bits/vector.tcc:238
#15 0x000000000040a8fb in BVHGenerator::generate (this=0x9fb578, mesh=0x7fffffffd140) at /home/aino/Documents/dev/gl_rays/src/mesh/bvh.cpp:87
#16 0x0000000000408891 in Renderer::init (this=0x9fb4f0) at /home/aino/Documents/dev/gl_rays/src/application/renderer.cpp:73
#17 0x0000000000405ed5 in App::init (this=0x7fffffffd3e0) at /home/aino/Documents/dev/gl_rays/src/application/app.cpp:23
#18 0x0000000000409f49 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffd5b8) at /home/aino/Documents/dev/gl_rays/src/main.cpp:7


Do you build with a compiler that have sanitizers (like GCC or Clang)? Then enable them and see what they say. And you typically get such an error if you write out of bounds of your allocated memory.

Already tried, I added add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror -fsanitize=address)

... and it crashes without the sanitizer giving you any output? Add -g -fsanitize=address,undefined and try again. Otherwise, run it in gdb and print a backtrace when it crashes.

This is my compile output: [  5%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/gl_rays.dir/src/mesh/bvh.cpp.o [ 10%] Linking CXX executable gl_rays [100%] Built target gl_rays
Nothing else.
Added the gdb bt in the question

That's the output when building it. In order to get something userful from the sanitizers, you need to run the program too. Btw, what line is line bvh.cpp:87 in the snippet you posted?

Sanitizers are run-time checks. It will report something when you run the program, not when building.

bvh.cpp:87 is current_nodes = new_nodes;
Apparently, there is some sanitizer output I didn't see: it is a heap-use-after-free:
freed on nodes.push_back(left_node);
written on one line after that: node->right_index = nodes.size();

At one line you do t_bvh *node = &nodes[node_index];, then you do a push_back on nodes later  nodes.push_back(left_node); which may reallocate and then you call node->has_children = true; so technically your code can exhibit undefined behavior (use after free) and anything can happen (including crashing)

Don't mess with pointers, replace node with an index into the vector and the problem goes away.

Have you run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker?  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's How to debug small programs.

As john and Pepijn Kramer pointed out, getting a pointer to a vector element is bad (t_bvh *node = &nodes[node_index];). It was fixed by replacing node with just nodes[node_index] and using that. Thanks.

The problem is not you're getting a pointer (or an iterator). The problem is that you use it after having done an operation which may do a reallocation, and so invalidate it.
